# Correct way to run upgrade script

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am running a module that was written by someone else. Inside the `sql` folder, I saw

```
mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.1.1-0.1.2.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.1.2-0.1.3.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.1.3-0.1.4.php
```

and the `<version>` inside `config.xml` is `0.1.4`. Do run the correct upgrade script, do I need to make the `<version>` value start at `0.1.0`, run the app, then move the version to `0.1.1`, and run the app again .. so on. Or can I just run the app at version '0.1.4', and Magento will understand that it need to run all other previous upgrade script?

Thank you very much

Comment: The version defined in xml must match the one in sql folder. In your case its `0.1.4`. If you run `0.1.4`, it will run from the install. For more info check this : http://prezi.com/rdb7ziapjhi6/magento-setup-resources/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just leave the version to `0.1.4`.
Here is how it works.
When installing a module, magento looks for the install script with the biggest version that is lower or equal to the version of the module and executes it.  [Read this for more details](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/26314/146).
Then it looks for all the upgrade scripts with versions between the install script determined above and the version you declared in `config.xml`.

So, in your case it will run all the scripts in the exact order you listed them in the question if you leave the version to `0.1.4`.

Answer (score 1):

The version is checked with the "core_resource" table in the database, and if the version is old then, magento searches for the necessary sql scripts to upgrade the module. To verify which version you are currently using, go to the core_resource table and check the version number for the module. Like wise if you remove the column associated with the module, then the next time any part of your magento installation is accessed, magento searches for the module, and gradually upgrades each one one by one.

Comment: I think the version is inside `core_resource` table??